# How do I add simple integer properties to an actor in TADS3?

Tags: interactive-fiction

I'm working on an IF game using TADS 3 and I'm looking for a way to keep track certain things on the player. The goal I'm trying to accomplish is tracking how many times a player has been damaged or has seen something unsettling.

I know TADS is similar to C++ or Java, but I'm not very proficient with those as languages. I tried just adding a local variable to the player Actor, but that threw errors. I found some documentation on adding properties to existing objects, but it seemed like those new properties needed to be based on object types that already existed. **I just need to know how to add my own integer variable to an object that can be altered and viewed by the environment/game code.**